# Using FlexLib on FlexMobile-Project

Tags: apache-flex, ipad, flex4.5, custom-component

I am trying to to use [FlexLib](https://github.com/flex-users/flexlib) in an MobileFlex Project with Adobe Flash Builder 4.6. For learning-reasons I am trying to create an iPad-Version of the ScheduleViewer1_Sample.mxml.

For some mysterious reason - at least a reason I don't understand - it's not working with the latest flexlib (2.6-M2).

With the former Version (2.5 - latest on [googlecode](https://code.google.com/p/flexlib/)) I just had to change the used namespaces and it worked like a charm.

For example i changed

```
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    xmlns:flexlib="http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/" 
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete();">
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
     //Stuff that just worked
  ]]>
 </mx:Script>  
 <flexlib:ScheduleViewer id="scheduleViewer" 
    width="600" height="400" 
    dataProvider="{ dataProvider }" 
    startDate="{ startDate }" endDate="{ endDate }" />         
</mx:Application>
```

to

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="MySchedule"
    xmlns:flexlib="http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        //I didn't change anything at the scripting part
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

      <flexlib:ScheduleViewer id="scheduleViewer"  
     width="600" height="400" 
     dataProvider="{ dataProvider }"       
     startDate="{ startDate }" endDate="{ endDate }" />
</s:View>
```

This worked. I don't know if this was correct to do it this way, but it worked. With the latest Version from [GitHub](https://github.com/flex-users/flexlib) it doesn't work anymore. I always get an error saying

> 'ScheduleViewer' declaration must be contained within the  tag, since it is not assignable to the default property's type 'Array' or element type 'mx.core.IVisualElement'.

How can I get the components from FlexLib to work in an iPad-Project?

**UPDATE:** Compiled FlexLib on my machine, now the error changed to

> Could not resolve `<flexlib:ScheduleViewer>` to a component implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Most FlexLib components pre-date the spark architecture which was introduced in Flex 4.  I would not expect them to be optimized for mobile usage, so you may run into problems there.

The The [IVisualElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IVisualElement.html) interface was also introduced in Flex 4, and it looks like the component you're trying to use does not implement it.

I suggest you try to get the source code for the component and recompile it in your current version of Flex.  As long as the component extends [UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html) you should be okay, as UIComponent implements IVisualElement.  If your component does not extend UIComponent, then you'll have to implement IVisualElement which may require component changes.

Comment: Thx a lot, compiling worked and looks good. Now I get a new error "Could not resolve <flexlib:ScheduleViewer> to a component implementation." What's wrong here?

PS: ScheduleViewer extends ScrollControlBase which extends UIComponent so it should work?!

Comment: @chiffre the problem is that you probably didn't set up the namespace URL when you recompiled the SWC.  You can either change the namespace to refer to a specific directory or set up the namespace URL for your library project you created. Here is my screencast on that: http://www.theflexshow.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/3/1/The-Flex-Show--Creating-Flex-Components--Episode-13-Custom-Namespace-URLs Although the process becomes extremely "temperamental" starting in Flash Builder 4.5 .

Comment: After accessing it directly from the code, I get the same error again - any tips left? Btw. the linked screencast is offline, always getting an 'Connection Failure'

Comment: I don't understand what "accessing it directly from the code" means.  You should be able to download the screencast using the download link.  I'll have to look into the "connection failure" issue.

Comment: Here is a direct link to view the screen online; it looks like our intermediary page for tracking is erroring out.  Most likely a side effect of a recent server upgrade.  http://www.theflexshow.com/video/episode28/index.htm

Comment: With "accessing it directly" I meant that I used the correct namespace to call it in the MXML-file. It's just the same error again...

Comment: @chiffre show us the code.  That error most likely means you are not using the correct namespace.  Sometimes using the same namespace name while changing the namespace causes odd issues.  So you should delete the namespace from the top level MXML tag; save your file, then add it back in.